# Beautiful soup: Finding <a> tags within a <td> but not within <sup> inside the <td>

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Some background here, please skip to the end if you're not interested in this.
I'm trying to scrape some data about singers on the Billboard Hot 100 and have run into the following problem while scraping information about what genres the singers belong to. I'm currently using the infobox table all singers have.
Eg. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lil_Nas_X

Inside the infobox, the genres cell is structured differently for different singers. Some singers like Lil Nas above has the genres tag inside a list

```html
    <th scope="row">Genres</th><td><div class="hlist hlist-separated">
        <ul>
        <li><a href="/wiki/Hip_hop_music" title="Hip hop music">Hip hop</a><sup id="cite_ref-Allmusic_genre_1-0" class="reference"><a href="#cite_note-Allmusic_genre-1">&#91;1&#93;</a></sup></li>
        <li><a href="/wiki/Country_rap" title="Country rap">country rap</a><sup id="cite_ref-Allmusic_genre_1-1" class="reference"><a href="#cite_note-Allmusic_genre-1">&#91;1&#93;</a></sup><sup id="cite_ref-2" class="reference"><a href="#cite_note-2">&#91;2&#93;</a></sup><sup id="cite_ref-3" class="reference"><a href="#cite_note-3">&#91;3&#93;</a></sup></li>
        <li>pop<sup id="cite_ref-Allmusic_genre_1-2" class="reference"><a href="#cite_note-Allmusic_genre-1">
```

While some others don't.

```html
    <th scope="row">Genres</th>
    <td><a href="/wiki/Alternative_rock" title="Alternative rock">Alternative rock</a>, 
    <a href="/wiki/Post-grunge" title="Post-grunge">post-grunge</a>
    <sup id="cite_ref-Villains_AMG_1-0" class="reference"><a href="#cite_note-Villains_AMG-1">&#91;1&#93;</a></sup></td></tr>
```

In these cases I run into a problem. If I extract all the **'a'** tags within **'td'** I'm getting the **'a'** tag within the cite note which is inside **'sup'** too.

I want to be able to extract the **'a'** tags inside **'td'** but not inside the **'sup'**. This is the code I am currently using for this portion.

```py
    cell_containing_genres = soup.find('th', string = "Genres").find_next('td') # This finds the next cell after the title Genres
            if cell_containing_genres.find_all('li') == []: #Extracting all the links from the cell above without list items
              genre_list = cell_containing_genres.find_all('a') 
              for genre in genre_list:
                genres.append(genre.get('href'))
            else: # Extracting all the links from the cell above with list items
              genre_list = cell_containing_genres.find_all('li')
              for genre in genre_list:
                genres.append(genre.find_all('a')[0].get('href'))
```

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Try ```cell_containing_genres.findChildren("a", recursive=False)```

Comment: @goalie1998 Hey thanks a lot. This works. Quick question. What does the recursive attribute mean?

Comment: Recursive basically means does it continue down the children into the grandchildren... etc. So in this case, if recursive were set to True, it would find the grandchild a tag which is a child of the sup tag (which is a child of td). I think ```findChildren()``` has been deprecated, so you can just use ```find_all(recursive=False)``` with the same effect.